# Caesar Cipher isn't printing final array

Tags: java, arraylist, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a Caesar cipher in Java, which asks you what word you want to shift and by how much. I had gotten an out of bounds exception, but that is fixed, and it still isn't working

Here is my code:

```
package cipher;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mycipher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> finalpro = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Integer> modlet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner consolereader= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
     char[] letters2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 
                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
     for(int i=0; i<letters2.length; i++){
         letters.add(letters2[i]);
     }
     System.out.println("what word would you like to cipher?");
     String original = consolereader.nextLine();
     System.out.println("how much would you like to shift it by");
     int shift = consolereader.nextInt();
     ArrayList<Character> userword = new ArrayList<Character>();
     for(int i=0; i<original.length();i++){
         userword.add(original.charAt(i));
     }
     for(int i=0; i<userword.size(); i++){
         if(userword.get(i)==letters2[i]){
             modlet.add(i%shift);
         }
     }
     for(int i=0;i<modlet.size(); i++){
         finalpro.add(letters2[modlet.get(i)]);
     }
     System.out.println(finalpro);

}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
for(int i=0; i<letters.size(); i++){
     if(userword.get(i)==letters2[i]){
         modlet.add(i%shift);
     }
 }
```

You are iterating over letters.size() which might be bigger than userword ArrayList. When you do userword.get(i) the index will be bigger than the userword.size(), hence the outOfBoundsException.

You should try changing the ascii code of the characters (for lower case letters):

```
for(Character charWord : userword){
    charWord = (char)(((((int) charWord - 97) + shift)%26) + 97);
}
```

This should replace the characters in userword with the characters shifted by "shift".

97 -> ascii code for "a"

26 -> number of letters in alphabeth.